# Can't access PostGIS data after Ubuntu update

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, upgrade

Our PostGIS database is installed on Ubuntu. Recently I made an upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. Now we can't access any PostGIS data. Example:

```
postgres=# select * from default_line limit 10;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

Ubuntu updated our PostgreSQL from 11.? to 11.7, but obviously deleted some important extension files. It installed a second PostgreSQL 12 with PostGIS 3.0. After some fiddling I can access both instances and I am willing and prepared to move the data to the new instance. But all tools like pg_dumpall, pg_upgrade also barf on missing extensions - apart from postgis-2.5 these are rtpostgis-2.5, plpython3, libpgrouting-2.6 and ogr_fdw.

So I think I need the appropriate .so files. I can't find the needed packages and don't know how to build them myself (from which source files?). What can I do?

EDIT: I have seen the similar questions mentioned in the comments. As far as I see none of the answers let me access the existing data.

EDIT three days later: I didn't find any way to access our data in Ubuntu 20.04. What I did is install Ubuntu 19.10 on another (virtual) PC with PostgreSQL 11/PostGIS 2.5 and let it access a copy of the database, this made the data readable again. I dumped the database and imported it in PostgreSQL 12 in Ubuntu 20.04. I had a "downtime" wednesday morning to friday morning where projects stalled, and I lost a night of sleep.

Comment: another similar issue/solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322877/postgresql-error-could-not-access-file-libdir-postgis-2-5